# How to return memory of terminated web worker safely?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

[image]
I made to use web workers to upload files.

It handle with small size files.

But with large size file, the speed is getting very slow and  my script causes web page collapse.

It does not return memory of web workers.

See the attachment.

The Dedicated Workers keep being accumulated and consume GB memory, when large file is being uploaded.

And I see this warning accumulating whenever web worker call `close()`

```bash
Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by them.
```

I throttled threadsQuantity as 5.

I think the number of web workers should not be exceeded more than 5.

```js
class Queue {
    constructor() {
        this.timestamp = new Date().getTime();
        this.activeConnections = {};
        this.threadsQuantity = 5;

    }
    async sendNext() {
        const activeConnections = Object.keys(this.activeConnections).length;
        if (activeConnections >= this.threadsQuantity) {
            return;
        }
        if (!this.chunksQueue.length) {
            if (!activeConnections) {
                this.complete();
            }
            return;
        }
        
        let chunkId = this.chunksQueue.pop();
        this.activeConnections[chunkId] = true;
        this.sendChunk( chunkId) ;
    }
  
    sendChunk( chunkId) {
        if (window.Worker) {
            let chunk = this.getChunk( chunkId)
            const myWorker = new Worker("/assets/js/worker.js?v=" + this.timestamp);
            myWorker.postMessage([this.timestamp, chunkId, chunk]);
            myWorker.onmessage = (e) => {
                var obj = JSON.parse(e.data)
                if( obj.success) {
                    delete this.activeConnections[chunkId];
                    this.sendNext()
                    close();
                } else {
                    sendChunk( chunkId);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried with `close()` , `self.close()` but all got same warning and failed.

I tried with `this.close()`, but it cause this error.

```bash
app.0a4dcc55.js:32 Uncaught TypeError: this.close is not a function
    at _.onmessage
```

How can I kill terminated web workers safely during process ?

Comment: It's `worker.terminate()` from the main thread, `close()` is from the Worker's side. But you should absolutely not use a Worker just to perform a network request, these are already not done on the CPU, and even if it was, or even if you were doing something hard on the CPU, you should absolutely not start one Worker per task, but only at max `navigator.hardwareConcurrency - 1` Workers, and distribute the all the tasks to these Workers.

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks for reply. I was thinking your comments.  So you mean that I have to re-use the web worker even that process is finished properly. right? May I should limit the number web worker instance?  Can you explain why you think it should be reused? and for my chrome `navigator.hardwareConcurrency ` is `undefined`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72679437/re-use-web-workers-vs-closing-spawning-new-once/72681399#72681399 and yes, you just post new messages to it when you need it to do new calculations. When idle it won't consume much. And as for `navigator.hardwareConcurrency`, you sure you typed it like that?